# App selector shows on startup instead of running my app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, startup

After creating a basic windows application with WPF, 
I added my app Executable to the registry so it should start up after turning the pc on.

However after turning on, windows seems to open my app but don't know how (asks me: "how do you want to open the application",with a list like notepad explorer etc.. )

I have also added my webstorm exe as a test and it opens on startup

```
 RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

        try
        {
            reg.SetValue("My application", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            reg.SetValue("Webstorm", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\WebStorm 2016.2\\bin\\WebStorm.exe");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You dont have permission", "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Other Exception " + e.Message, "Other Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Your app succesfilly registered", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay.... Not sure why this works..

But changing this line:

```
 reg.SetValue("My application", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

to this:

```
reg.SetValue("FirstApp","\""  + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + "\"");
```

made the magic...
The output in the registry looks exactly the same... but it works and opens my app..

Comment: It seems, that you have a spaces in a path to executable. Adding double quotes will solve the issue, otherwise windows can't recognize a path properly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only .Location, add your apps filename to it - with .exe.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, .location already has the full path with my app's filename .exe
like: .../bin/myApp.exe